# Telephone Number State Code In Dropdown + Phone Number

Tags: html, forms

[image]

I'm not really sure how to ask this question. So, I hope you can understand by looking at my photo here.

I'm creating HTML form to grab subscriber's telephone number at first stage. Now, I want to change it by having state code in front using `<select>` and `<option>` followed by the rest of the phone number in `<input>`.

Eg: +6010123456789

The telephone number field has `name="telephone"` and `id="telephone"`. I'm not really sure how write this. Hope you can help me with this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first, it is best to differentiate the ID and the name attribute. Another one is something you should do with your server-side code. So, here is the example with your current data assuming this you are using native PHP using string compare and substring method.

```
$phone = 6010123456789;
```

Inside the select combo box:

```
<select name="stateCode" id="stateCode">
        <option value="6011" <?php if(!(strcmp(substr($phone,0,4),6011))){ echo "selected=\"selected\"";}?>>6011</option>
        <option value="6012" <?php if(!(strcmp(substr($phone,0,4),6012))){ echo "selected=\"selected\"";}?>>6012</option>
        <option value="6013" <?php if(!(strcmp(substr($phone,0,4),6013))){ echo "selected=\"selected\"";}?>>6013</option>
        <option value="6014" <?php if(!(strcmp(substr($phone,0,4),6014))){ echo "selected=\"selected\"";}?>>6014</option>
        <option value="6016" <?php if(!(strcmp(substr($phone,0,4),6016))){ echo "selected=\"selected\"";}?>>6016</option>
        <option value="6017" <?php if(!(strcmp(substr($phone,0,4),6017))){ echo "selected=\"selected\"";}?>>6017</option>
        <option value="6019" <?php if(!(strcmp(substr($phone,0,4),6019))){ echo "selected=\"selected\"";}?>>6019</option>
        <option value="6010" <?php if(!(strcmp(substr($phone,0,4),6010))){ echo "selected=\"selected\"";}?>>6010</option>
      </select>
```

And the input box:

```
<input type="number" name="cellNumber" id="cellNumber" value="<?php echo substr($number,4,11) ?>" required/>
```

So, if the phone number is **6010123456789**, the select box will automatically select the area code with the same value, and the input box will be populated with cellNumber.

That's it, upon submission, you just need to concat the data from the select and input box to form one new variable.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're wanting to have the selected value and the contents of the textbox be POSTed to the server as a single concatenated value, despite being two separate form fields, so that your server-side code can remain the same, reading the POST variable named "telephone"?

If that is your aim, I don't think you'll be able to leave the server-side code untouched. You could have both the `<select>` and the `<input>` with the same `name` attribute value, and the server-side code would receive a comma-separated value for the variable named "telephone". Without anything more complex, that's about as close as you can get.

(Remember that the `<select>` and the `<input>` cannot share an `id` attribute value)